# How to get values from input in sap.ui.table.Table?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

In `sap.ui.table.Table` I have input field in one column. It will get nearly 300 records of data from back-end and binded in other columns.

User manually enters in the input field. Further, when he clicks on submit button I have to take all values from all input as array. Please give suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using data binding of table, as invoking `getRows()` on `Table` control to access `Input` fields of each row would not help in this case;it only returns only currently visible rows and you have around 300 records to access.

Here is the solution:

1. Get all data from back-end in `JSONModel`.
2. Add one property say *inputValue* to each item in model's data by iterating over it.
3. Bind this model to table and use *inputValue* property in table's template to bind column containing `Input` fields.

As `JSONModel` supports two-way binding, all the values which user has entered in an `Input` fields are available in your model.

And, lastly iterate over model's data to get *inputValue* for each row.

Above steps in action:

Step 1 and 2:

```
setModelForTable: function() {
    var oModel = sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel( < URLToLoadJSON > );
    var length = oModel.getData().results.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var path = "/results/" + i + "/inputValue";
        oModel.setProperty(path, "");
    }
}
```

Step 3:

Now, that you have model with *inputValue* property in all the items of data, set the model on table; which will show all the `Input` fields in columns empty initially and will update the corresponding model entry as user modifies it.

```
<t:Column>
    <t:label>
        <Text text="User Input" />
    </t:label>
    <t:template>
        <Input value="{inputValue}" />
    </t:template>
</t:Column>
```

Finally, get all entered values in array.

```
var length = oModel.getData().results.length;
var aInputvalues = []
for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    var path = "/results/" + i + "/inputValue";
    aInputvalues.push(oModel.getProperty(path));
}
```

Comment: Hi dopedev, Thanks for ur suggestion. Can you explain in detail ? Please

Comment: Sure, give me some time!

Comment: Thank you dopedev. I am using sap.m.Input

Comment: Thank you dopedev. Hey another suggestion how to make validation for all user inputs to be not empty when user clicks submit button and display a message box that one field is empty ???

Comment: Kindly post it as separate question as answering it here will be out of scope of mentioned question, also requirement is bit tricky with `sap.ui.table.Table` and requires work around

Answer (score 1):

I had the case which is a bit similar and I did it in the following way. Will work if you really do not need records which are not changed.

1. have a variable to store [] of changed records
2. Attach change to input field
3. on change push changed record to a variable

   ```
   var source = event.getSource();
   source.getModel().getProperty(source.getBindingContext().getPath());
   ```

or the value of the input field.

```
    event.getSource().getValue();
```

In case you have a record Id you can just push this ID and input value.
4. on submit iterate through an []